# Getting the boundary of numpy array shape with a hole

Tags: python, numpy, scipy-spatial

I am trying to obtain an ndarray of points along the boundary of a shape denoted by 1's in the array. I tried using `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` but the boundary created by the convex hull did not account for the hole in the middle of the shape (I need a boundary around the hole too). This is the kind of boundary I am trying to create from the array. How can I account for the hole in the shape?

[image]

The colored in area is the area that the boundary points should be calculated from.
[image]

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d, ConvexHull


arr = np.array([
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],
    [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],])

coords = []
for x in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for y in range(arr.shape[1]):
        if arr[x][y] > 0:
            tile = [x,y]
            coords.append(tile)
            # print("tile", tile)
coords = np.array(coords)
# print(coords)

hull = ConvexHull(coords)
plt.plot(coords[:,0], coords[:,1], 'o')
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(coords[simplex, 0], coords[simplex, 1], 'k-')

plt.plot(coords[hull.vertices,0], coords[hull.vertices,1], 'r--', lw=2)
plt.plot(coords[hull.vertices[0],0], coords[hull.vertices[0],1], 'ro')
```

Comment: The image is not clear to me, for example, why is `(3, 2)` part of the frontier but `(1, 3)` is not?

Comment: @vlizana updated the image to show image I am trying to make a boundary from

Comment: thanks, but I still can't tell if you're going for a v4 or v8 frontier. For example in the picture you just uploaded, using a v8 neighborhood every point (1) would be part of the frontier, where as in the v4 kind there are a few who are interior points.

Comment: In the picture I drew out a v4 frontier. I presume the method would be the same for v4 as it is for v8 too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky, but if you convolve the zeros with the right kernel (v4 or v8) you get the outer part plus the frontier, so if you do an `and` kind of operation with the inner part you get only the frontier. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

arr = np.array([
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],
    [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
])

# v4 example, 
kernel = np.array([
    [0,1,0],
    [1,0,1],
    [0,1,0],
])

# you have to zero pad first in order to get the edges
padded = np.pad(arr, ((1, 1), (1, 1)), 'constant', constant_values=0)

# the `astype(bool)` is for normalization
# the `and` operation in this case is the elementwise product
frontier = convolve2d(1-padded, kernel, mode='valid').astype(bool) * arr
```